# Convert value string to percentage

Tags: powerbuilder

Using powerbuilder script, what is the easiest way to convert the string "0.5" to "50%"?

I've tried converting to Double first, but Double("0.5") returns 0..

Comment: I am not pretty sure if this is an easiest way to do that, but you can parse the string using '.' symbol as a delimiter. You will get an array of 2 sub-strings. In your case it will be "0" and "5". After that convert both of them into integer. Next step would be to multiply 1 number on 100, second one on 10. This will give you percent.

Comment: If you post an answer with this with code I'll mark it as correct. I hoped I did'nt have to go through with this though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any specific decimal separator other than `.` or `,`?

In PB, the conversion from a string value to another type uses the regional settings. The same problem arises for converting other types like date or time.

Beware of the double (or float) type: floating point except for scientific computing is a painful path. Prefer the decimal type.

Here (with a coma as decimal separator) the following code seems to do what you are looking for:

```
dec value

value = dec("0,5")
value *= 100
value = int(value) //intermediate cast to integer to remove the decimal part

messagebox("percent", string(value)+"%")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect after doing a Replace on '.' with ','

Answer (score 1):

did you try Double("0,5") insteed ? It may be a regional mistake.

Comment: might be, but I'm receiving "0.5" from the server which gives me no other choice than to replace it I guess.

Comment: Changing "." to "," had no effect btw